# How to redirect on button click on user is not logged in in django

Tags: django, hyperlink

Hey django gang how's it going? I wanted to know how I can redirect a user to login page if he is not logged in when he clicks a button which serves different purpose when the user is logged in.

For example:

I have a button which acts as modal popup button when the user is logged in but will redirect the user to login page if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the convenient login_required() decorator:

```
   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

    @login_required
    def my_view(request):
      ...
```

Comment: Yes but I want users to see the page without logging in

Comment: what do you mean by without loggin in. you see the login page if you are not logged in.

Comment: I am saying that I want users to see the main page without logging in

Comment: than just work with the url and just make sure to not include that login decorator. This way you can view that page and no login is required. upload some code so that guiding you will be easy.

Comment: No sir/mam you are not understanding what I am saying. Have you used instagram? There you can stalk your fav celebrity without logging in but when you try to click the like button it simply redirects you to the login page

Answer (score 0):

the button should trigger a view, which checks if the user is authenticated
For example:

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
      # render popup
   else:
      # redirect to login page
```

you can also handle this in your template, for example:

template.html

```
<body>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        {# show button that trigger popup #}
    {% else %}
       {# show button that redirects to login page #}
    {% endif %}
</body>
```